# How to correctly use Copy Constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I am having trouble understanding how to call/create copy constructors. Does my problem lie within how I am trying to call this in main? Or is there a certain way this needs to be accomplished in the Animal.cpp.

If this were to be working, would I be able to invoke a copy constructor with derived classes using Animal as the base class?

Animal.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{

}

Animal::Animal(string s, string c,string a, string d)
{
    species = s;
    classification = c;
    animal = a;
    desc = d;

}

Animal::Animal(const Animal &obj)
{
   //What should be placed in here?
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Animal.h"


using namespace std;

int main(){



    Animal *elephant = new Animal("Straight-Tusked","Mammal","Elephant","Grazer");

    Animal *elephant2 = new Animal(*elephant);

}
```

Comment: You have to define how to make an `Animal` with another `Animal`. Copy the values maybe?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do you come from a Java or C# background? Because in C++ you don't have to use `new` to create new objects. Doing e.g. `Animal elephant(...);` is perfectly okay. And then you can simply do `Animal elephat2 = elephant;` and the copy-constructor will be invoked.

Comment: Please show the declaration of class `Animal`, or we cannot tell.

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers and `new` dynamic allocation? Why are you missing `delete`?

Comment: Also, please read about [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero), because it might be possible that you don't need to explicitly define a copy-constructor at all, and that the compiler-generated one will work well.

Comment: I've been reading the Dietel & Dietel c++ and following along. They use the 'class' *ptr = new 'class'() syntax.

Comment: No idea what "Dietel & Dietel" is (Deitel?), but it sounds like you want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, always use member initalizers if possible:

```
Animal::Animal(const string &s, const string &c,const string &a, const string &d)
   : species(s), classification(c), animal(a), desc(d)
{
}
```

Also note the explicit pass by const-reference. If you pass `string s`, you get an implicit copy of the parameter. The compiler probably [copy-elides](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) this, so you won't *see* any difference, but the elision is an optimization that may or may not happen.

As for the copy constructor, going from what we see from the `Animal` class, you probably want something like this:

```
Animal::Animal(const Animal &obj)
   : species(obj.species)
   , classification(obj.classification)
   , animal(obj.animal)
   , desc(obj.description)
{
}
```

The copy constructor should make a copy of `obj` by assigning the appropriate values for `*this`. Note that the above is also what the default, auto-generated copy constructor does (if no other fields are present).

Because the above is essentially the same as the default copy constructor, in C++11 and above, you can tell the compiler to explicitly generate the [default copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions):

```
class Animal {
    Animal(const Animal &) = default;
};
```

As by the [rule-of-three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (rule-of-five nowadays), you probably also want a copy-assign operator.

And finally, when you have `new` somewhere, you will need to `delete` the object. C++ does not do (built-in) reference counting nor does it have a garbage collector. If you forget to `delete` a `new`d object, you have a memory leak.

As noted in the comments, it is, however, perfectly possible to just declare an `Animal` object by declaring a variable

```
Animal a(
    "Hippopotamus",
    "Mammalia",
    "Hippopotamus",
    "from the movie"
);
```

This will get cleaned up automatically (and its destructor called) when the program leaves the current scope.

Comment: I would consider mentioning an option to declare `Animal(const Animal&) = default;` since this behaviour is default.

Comment: @Zereges ... if using C++11 and up ;-). And yes, added.

Comment: "rule of three" is "rule of zero" here ... the default-generated versions of everything are correct so the fewer the better

Comment: If I were to put anything in my constructors, what would merit filling the body of them? The way you are creating these the bodies are empty.

Comment: @Genesis You do anything in the constructor that is needed to get you a proper object. Think of e.g. doing initial calculations based on the parameters and the like or checking `species` against a list of well-known species (don't do this). As of now, the `Animal` class is too simple, it does not even need an (explicit) copy constructor.

Comment: My last Question: would this work if if I used inheritance and copied a child of this class? That had the same parameters?

Comment: @Genesis Depends. If you copy e.g. an `Hippo` class (subclass of `Animal`), you get a new `Animal` class with those properties of `Hippo` that where already in `Animal`. The copy is reduced to what's available in the super class. There's a reason why C++ polymorphism only works via references and pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an accepted answer, I thought I would address your comment in your code

```
//What should be placed in here?
```

A copy constructor is exactly what it's name describes it as. It is a function that constructs an object from another object of the same type. So the short answer is that what goes into a copy constructor is code that creates a new object instance, using an existing instance as the source for construction.

The compiler creates a copy constructor if you do not supply one yourself. In the compiler's copy constructor, the instance is 'bitwise copied', which means all of the data members of the class are copied bit for bit.

This can present a problem if one or more of your data members are pointers. In a bitwise copy, the copy instance's pointers will point to the same objects as the object it is copied from. You may want to copy construct the objects it points to, when the object is copied. This is one of the reasons for supplying your own copy constructor.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
     int a;
     int b;

     Foo() : a(0), b(0) {}
     Foo(int ain, int bin) : a(ain), b(bin) {}
     ~Foo() {}
}
class Bar
{
     double z;
     Foo* foo;
public:
     Bar() : z(0) , foo(new Foo) {}
     Bar(double zin, Foo* fooin) : z(zin), foo(fooin) {}
     // Copy constructor below
     Bar(const Bar &rhs) : z(rhs.z) , foo(new Foo(rhs.foo->a, rhs.foo->b)) {}
}
```

Bar's copy constructor will also construct a new Foo object and point to it.
Note that Bar's copy constructor could also be done like this:

```
Bar(const Bar &rhs) : z(rhs.z) , foo(new Foo((const Foo&)*(rhs.foo))) {}
```

Which will use the compiler's default copy constructor for Foo.

While member initializers are preferred, it's useful to remember that constructors are functions, so you can call any other constructor from the copy constructor using the **this** pointer like so:

```
Animal::Animal(const Animal &obj)
{
    this->Animal(obj.s, obj.c, obj.a, obj.d);
}
```

Note that the following will not work:

```
Animal::Animal(const Animal &obj)
{
    Animal(obj.s, obj.c, obj.a, obj.d);
}
```

Because it will be treated as an expression and create an anonymous object, and not a function call to the constructor (on my compiler at least anyway).